# Azure blob storage file path limitation

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Does the Azure blob storage services has the 260 char limitation that Windows has?

Or how deep can my folder hierarchy be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the Azure blob storage services has the 260 char limitation that
>   Windows has?

No, Blob storage file paths can be longer than Windows file paths.

The full URL of the Blob is made up of both the Container name as well as the Blob name. Each of these have different length requirements.

- Container names must be from 3 through 63 characters long.
- Blob names must be at least 1 character and cannot exceed 1,024 characters long.

> Or how deep can my folder hierarchy be?

Af far as folder structure goes, the Blob isn't actually stored within folders, but the name does support the use of slashes '/' to create path segments. The number of path segments in a blob name cannot exceed 254. Basically, you can go 254 "folders" deep.

For more information see the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135715.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> Does the Azure blob storage services has the 260 char limitation that
>   Windows has?

No. Azure Blob Storage doesn't have this limitation simply because it is an object store and not a file storage system.

> Or how deep can my folder hierarchy be?

Based on the documentation [`here`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/azure/dd135715.aspx):

- A blob name must be at least one character long and cannot be more than 1,024 characters long.
- The number of path segments comprising the blob name cannot exceed 254. A path segment is the string between consecutive delimiter characters (e.g., the forward slash '/') that corresponds to the name of a virtual directory.

However please keep in mind that you would still run into this 260 char limits if you try to download the blob on a Windows system and want to preserve the folder hierarchy.